# C# Minimize to Tray

Tags: c#, minimize, trayicon

I know you will be thinking "Not again this question", as I found like a hundred results when I searched for it. But when I put in the code as described on the pages here, it just minimizes to right above the start menu.

This is the code I use (I added a message box to see if the code gets triggered, but the message box never pops up):

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Works1");
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Because I don't know if it links to `Form1` or `Form`, I have tried both, to no avail.

```
private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Works");
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Now, when you double click on the `Form`, it puts this line in the `Form1.Designer.cs`:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Do I need a similar line to trigger the minimize event?

As you can see, I am completely lost :)

Oh, and it doesn't minimize to the taskbar, as I am using the following code to hide the form on run:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Visible = false; // Hide form window.
    ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the event

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

[Creating Event Handlers on the Windows Forms Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys, that got the job done :)

I used both your answers, but I can only credit one person. I creditted Andy, because of the link for creating Event Handles, but ByteBlast, I want to thank you too, as your suggestions were very helpfull!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component to your Form. Make sure you set an icon via the properties pane otherwise it will be invisible.
2. Create an event handler for the form's [`Control.SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event. In that event handler place the following code:

sample code:

```
private void MainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

And then to make the form visible again the [`NotifyIcon.MouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.mousedoubleclick.aspx) event handler you can place the following code:

```
private void trayIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    ShowInTaskbar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing you need to know is **events**. Events are triggered when certain things happen to your form (or any control). For example, when the form is resized, or loaded, or clicked, an *event* is raised. You can hook into this event to execute your own code when the event happens.

In your case you want to execute code to minimize the form, on the event that the form is resized. So you need to hook your method to the resize event. The name of your method is not relevant, so let's use a better name:

```
private void HideWhenMinimized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Works1");
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

To hook your `HideWhenMinimized` method into the `Resize` event of the form, you have to do it like this:

```
this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.HideWhenMinimized);
```

If you add that line of code in the form's constructor or `Load` event, then your code gets called as soon as the form is resized.